# Javascript scraping: data not loaded when fetched?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

Trying to fiddle around with site scraping. The example I'm using is this site:

> http://www.oddsshark.com/nhl/computer-picks

With the goal being to use data to help with hockey pool etc etc

Now, when I do a simple fetch like:

```
 var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.oddsshark.com/nhl/computer-picks');

  Logger.log(data.getBlob().getDataAsString());
```

None of the data in the body shows up. I assume its because the data is being retrieved from somewhere via javascript, but thats kinda the end of my rope in terms of understanding web development. I guess if that is the case, two parts,

1. How can I see where in that HTML that I'm grabbing the data is being fetched
   and
2. How do I fetch it?

Thanks!
-Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works. Since you are using [Logger.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata), you have to view logs (View -> Logs) in the script editor to see the fetched response, which [I pasted here](http://pastebin.com/z4sHaTpv). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! So yes I should have mentioned that I did check the log. The issue is, for example today if you look in the actual webpage there is a game between arizona and pittsburgh. But, if you search for the word 'Arizona' in the logged response, it's not there, so I assume its being loaded later or something?

Comment: Oops. Turns out the log just has a character limit but it was working, you're right :)